# Ionic4 hardware mobile back buttion issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

if click on the back button to close ionic4 app in android mobile getting following error
code to close the app:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
    });
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

error:

```
 E/Capacitor/Plugin/Console: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
    Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this snippet workaround

```js
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
})

// To prevent interference with ionic's own backbutton handling
// you can subscribe with a low priority instead
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
  // and ionic doesn't already know what to do (close modals etc...)
})
```

PS: Hope you'd check whether `platform` module is imported or not.

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {

  }
}
```

Comment: @RajeshYadav - this might be also a hint for you - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hardware-back-button-with-ionic-4/137905/65

Comment: @RajeshYadav - added a post script answer. would you please check it?

Comment: D - I imported Platform using code provided by u, but after splash screen, it is showing above error  NullInjectorError: No provider for t!

Comment: If click back button not triggering above method provided by u

Comment: would you update your question with full error log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196818/discussion-between-ali-d-and-rajesh-yadav).

Comment: import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
       subscription: any;
    constructor(private navController: NavController
                , public platform: Platform
    ) {
    }
    ngOnInit() { }

Comment: ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
        });
    }
    ionViewWillLeave() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}